# Неуловимая ошибка прерывает цикл "aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError" (while, loop, телеграм бот)

Tags: python-3.x, циклы, aiogram, while, обработка-ошибок

Имеется телеграм-бот на aiogram (2.19).

```
# ... пропущен код ...

async def current_info(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    current_data = {}
    while True:
        local_file = open(json_file, 'r')
        local_data = local_file.get('data')
        if local_data and local_data != current_data:
            current_data = local_data
            await message.answer(str(current_data))
        local_file.close()
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

# ... пропущен код ...

def register_handlers(dp: Dispatcher):
    # ... пропущен код ...
    # InfoState.ok - состояние успешной авторизации
    dp.register_message_handler(current_info, lambda message: message.text == "Начать 
                                смотреть актуальные обновления", state=InfoState.ok)

# ... пропущен код ...
```

Выше представил упрощенную структуру. То есть есть *корутина* принимающая команду `"Начать смотреть актуальные обновления"` 1 раз - после чего начинающая бесконечные запросы в `"json_file"` на наличие чего-то нового и после отправки этого юзеру.

Все работает хорошо, за исключением одной вещи. Когда проскакивает:

```
aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError
```

бот свою работу аварийно не завершает - он продолжает функционировать и отвечать на прямые запросы юзеров: "команда - запрос". Но с цикла `while True` вылетает. И самое худшее, что я не могу **словить** эту ошибку - и, например, вызвать сообщение юзеру, где он перезапустит цикл кнопкой `"Начать смотреть актуальные обновления"`. Функция с `while` перезагружается, без перезапуска бота, без проблем. Проблема в том, что ты не можешь быть уверен случилась ли ошибка и пора перезапустить цикл, или просто нет новый данных в `json_file`

**Желаемый результат** для меня - **отлавливание** этой ошибки для дальнейшего **перезапуска** цикла `while True`, но не всего бота полностью.

Попытки обернуть `try except` мой `if __name__ == '__main__': asyncio.run(main())` и `await message.answer`, все тело while ни к чему не привели. Ошибка происходит вне моего кода, но ломает цикл в моем коде.

Заранее прошу прощения за глупость, и большое спасибо за любые Ваши ответы и подсказки!

Весь код ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант, сделать синхронность, приведу пример...

```
from threading import Thread

def thisisfunc():
 while(True):
    print('world')

thread1 = Thread(target=thisisfunc())

thread1.start()
thread1.join()
```

думаю поможет...

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к вопросу, он меня прямо не мучает (стабильный хостинг), но я его до сих пор не решил. Как быть с асинхронным await message.answer(str(current_data))? Без цикла в корутине не обойтись. Через threading можно добавить условную функцию чекера, которая будет проверять "а жив ли цикл" по средствам того, что цикл будет выносить на третью сторону какой-то флаг со временем, когда он последний раз выполнял работу, если это время более условных 10 секунд - пора его воскрешать ресетом всего мейн процесса. Но будем честны - вариант очень неэлегантный, и костыльный.